# Write CSV file from scraped data with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

This is how I scraped the data using Beautifulsoup.

```
comments =[]
users_list = []
users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_6lAjh')

for user in users:
    users_list.append(user.text)

i = 0
texts_list = []
texts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('C4VMK')

for txt in texts:
    texts_list.append(txt.text.split(users_list[i])[1].replace("\r"," ").replace("\n"," "))
    i += 1
    comments_count = len(users_list)

for i in range(1, comments_count):
    user = users_list[i]
    text = texts_list[i]
    print("User ",user)
    print("Text ",text)
    print()
    comments.append(users_list[i])
    comments.append(texts_list[i])
    idxs = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('@', text)]
    for idx in idxs:
        handle = text[idx:].split(" ")[0]

print(handle)
```

This is the text data I have which are username, comments, and number of likes from instagram. 
' heyyy 3w1 likeReply' -> 'heyyy' is comment in here, 3w means the comment was written 3weeks ago, 1 like is number of likes

```
print(comments)
```

```
['User1',
 '  3w1 likeReply',
 'User2',
 '  3w1 likeReply',
 'User3',
 ' Looking good! Collab, DM "bruteimpact.fashion 3wReply',
 'User4',
 ' heyyy 3w5 likeReply']
```

I want to save this into CSV file that looks like this(three columns- ID, Comments, likes_count):

```
ID  Comments  likes_count
User1        0
User2        1
User3 Looking good! Collab, DM "bruteimpact.fashion  0
User4 heyyy    5
```

so far this is the code I wrote but is far from the result I want to get and I do not know how to get to the final destination at all. Plus, I have no idea how to make separate 'likes_count' by detaching the number of likes from the comment data I have. However, I would be satisfied with CSV file with just "ID" and "Text" column without "likes_count". Please help me!

```
fields = ["User", "Text"]
rows = [comments]
filename = "insta_records.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Can you give us some example code to run? What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: how did you get it ? Maybe you can use BeautifulSoup in better way to get it as separated element. Eventually use `split(' ')` or `rsplit(' ')` to split it - but there are missing spaces to do it correctly.

Comment: @EdWard I edited it! I don't know if it helps....

Comment: @furas I added codes describing how I got my data!

Comment: and where is url for this data - create minimal working code so we could run it. With current data you have to first transform them before you will try to save in csv. You have to split text to columns, get number from `3w1` (ie. using `regex`), etc.

Comment: you would have to also group user with its comment - ie. `for user, text in zip(comments[::2], comments[1::2]): print(user, text) rows.append([user, text])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have flat list so you could use `zip` to group user and its comment

```
comments = ['User1',
 '  3w1 likeReply',
 'User2',
 '  3w1 likeReply',
 'User3',
 ' Looking good! Collab, DM "bruteimpact.fashion 3wReply',
 'User4',
 ' heyyy 3w5 likeReply']

rows = []
for user, text in zip(comments[::2], comments[1::2]):
    print(user, text)
    #rows.append([user, text])


fields = ["User", "Text"]
filename = "insta_records.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile: 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    csvwriter.writerow(fields) 
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Result on screen

```
User1   3w1 likeReply
User2   3w1 likeReply
User3  Looking good! Collab, DM "bruteimpact.fashion 3wReply
User4  heyyy 3w5 likeReply
```

And in file

```
User,Text
User1,  3w1 likeReply
User2,  3w1 likeReply
User3," Looking good! Collab, DM ""bruteimpact.fashion 3wReply"
User4, heyyy 3w5 likeReply
```

---

To create other columns you would have to first edit comments - `split()`, `replace()`, 
slice `[start:end]`,  etc.

```
rows = []
for user, text in zip(comments[::2], comments[1::2]):
    parts = text.rsplit(' ', 2)#[:-1]
    parts.insert(0, user)
    print(parts)
    rows.append(parts)
```

Result on screen

```
['User1', ' ', '3w1', 'likeReply']
['User2', ' ', '3w1', 'likeReply']
['User3', ' Looking good! Collab, DM', '"bruteimpact.fashion', '3wReply']
['User4', ' heyyy', '3w5', 'likeReply']
```

but there is missing space in `'3wReply'` so it doesn't split it correctly and it would need more work to split it correctly.

BTW: when you have `3w5` then you can `split('w')` to get `['3', '5']` but in HTML can be other text instead of `w` so it would need more work. Maybe using more complex rules in `BeautifulSoup` you could better split it.